# Difference between vector and its reference when debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, pass-by-reference

The program itself is simple

```
template <typename T>
void foo(std::vector<T>& data) {
   // ...
}
```

and

```
template <typename T>
void bar(std::vector<T> data) {
   // ...
}
```

I try to debug these two functions in `CLion`, but the information of variable `data` is quite different.

If passing by value (`bar`), `data` is exactly what I passed. However, if passing by reference (`foo`), then the size of `data` is always 1 and combined with `__begin__` and `__end__` iterators, not underlying values explicitly.

So, If `reference` is just an `alias`, why would `reference` cause such difference?

When accessing the `data` inside the two functions, they behave the same. What confuses me is that the displaying styles of debugging are different.

Debug for `foo`:

[image]

Debug for `bar`:

[image]

Comment: I am sure you are missing something. A reference will look just like the original object. Perhaps you need to step into the first line of the function to see the reference variable in its accurate state.

Comment: Those two functions can behave the same (for example, `for-loop`), but the display styles of debugging are different. @RSahu

Comment: This is probably a behaviour of CLion, not a C++ problem per se.   Debuggers don't always handle (display, etc) objects passed by reference in the same way they handle objects passed by value. Try stepping into the function to the first declaration or statement to see if anything changes.  However - ignoring the debugger - the two approaches are not equivalent:  any changes of `data` within `foo()` will be visible to the caller, but not changes within `bar()` (which receives a COPY of the object passed).

Comment: If that is indeed the case, I would say the debugger is a rather poor debugger.

Comment: @RSahu as you can see, the built-in debugger is bundled LLDB (6.0.1). Is it a `bug` of the debugger tool?

Comment: @Peter Yes, I know the differences between passing by value and passing by reference. What I want to know is **the reason of the counter-intuitive debugger information** .

Comment: Yes, users experienced in CLion would be able to tell whether that is a bug. I am not one of them.

Comment: @chenzhongpu - it's a property of the compiler (what debugging information it outputs to help the debugger, whether that information is suppressed, etc etc) and the debugger (what it does with information it receives).  If the compiler implements pass-by-reference by passing the address of the object in a machine register, the debugger needs help from the compiler (e.g. to work out what has actually been passed).  As such, there is no universal answer.   If you want a specific answer, you'll need to ask the developers of CLion.

Comment: Maybe it is displaying the reference as if it were a pointer (normal ABI for passing by reference is to pass a pointer)